# Why can't I see the comment that my mailbox claims to have come?

Tags: support

In my mailbox I see this:

> Jun, 23 Difference between "day after tomorrow" and "day after next"
>   comment: @KonradViltersten There is often a down-vote as soon as I post, and sometimes after it is checkma...

So I click on the link and I come to the page but there's no comment like this. What's up with that? Can I somehow get to see the comment even if it's been deleted?

Comment: It was deleted by its author just two minutes later. Deleted comments cannot be viewed by regular users. Why they still do show up in inboxes is another matter, but I think it's actually by design (though the reasons escape me right now).

Comment: The same thing has happened to me several times, it's like seeing a preview, you go to visit the commenter and there's nothing. A tantalising glimpse and then... poof! Comments as I understand them are ephemeral unlike posted answers.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Can I learn what that used said, please? I believe he was onto something interesting...

Comment: @ Konrad: I think you should assume if the original poster deleted his comment, he regrets having said whatever he did, and *doesn't want you to read it*. Personally, I would be somewhat disappointed in any mod who overrode that assumption and acceded to your request. Ping the user in chat (or anywhere he's posted a question, answer, or comment) and take it from there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, I assumed that said person didn't want **others** to see what they wrote. But you're making a very good point - it might be me included. I'd contact him on chat but I don't know how to "*ping*" people there. Care to hint? Also, I'm a bit (quite large bit, in fact) lazy so if it's too much hustle, I'll probably disregards the whole thing. Still, I'd like to know how to "*ping*" others, in case a more urgent need arises in the future.

Comment: @RegDwigнt How can I improve the question? I see I got downvoted. Can't tell why...

Comment: @ Konrad: I don't know if pinging in chat works if the target isn't currently logged in to chat, but I kinda doubt it. If I were in your position I'd just check the user's profile and randomly select any question, answer, or comment he contributed (asking @him to meet me in chat, after which I'd delete the now-redundant comment).